# Known depth and edges query efficency

Tags: orientdb

My data looks like this:

a ---> b ---> c

a, b and c are vertices, there is one a, but multiple b-s and c-s (tree structure).

My a ---> b edge is of one class (let's call it ab class), while the b ---> c edge is another (bc class).

I need a query which will, given the name of a, produce x number of c-s.

So far, I found that this works:

```
select expand(set(out("ab").out("bc"))) from a where name='aName' limit x
```

Questions:

1. Can this query be improved?
2. How can I only select, for example, names of c-s, and not the whole records?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that query can only be improved if you define an **index** on **A.name** property.

About your second question:

```
create class A extends V
create class B extends V
create class C extends V    

create class AB extends E
create class BC extends E

create vertex A set name = 'aName'
create vertex B set name = 'bName0'
create vertex B set name = 'bName1'
create vertex C set name = 'cName0'
create vertex C set name = 'cName1'
create vertex C set name = 'cName2'
create vertex C set name = 'cName3'    

create edge AB from (select from A where name = 'aName') to (select from B where name = 'bName0')
create edge AB from (select from A where name = 'aName') to (select from B where name = 'bName1')
create edge BC from (select from B where name = 'bName0') to (select from C where name = 'cName0')
create edge BC from (select from B where name = 'bName0') to (select from C where name = 'cName2')
create edge BC from (select from B where name = 'bName1') to (select from C where name = 'cName1')
create edge BC from (select from B where name = 'bName1') to (select from C where name = 'cName3')
```

These queries may help you:

```
select from (select expand(out("AB").out("BC").include('name')) from A where name = 'aName') limit 3
// or
select name from (select expand(out("AB").out("BC")) from A where name = 'aName') limit 3
```

Comment: A.name already has an index. Thanks for the tip on how to select name!

Comment: I have one more question: I want to paginate using the same query, but adding skip gives me an empty result. Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like an issue. It's only happening in subqueries since `select from C skip 2 limit 2` is returning the expected. The parser has some problems that will be fixed in 2.1. Have you tried 2.1-rc1?

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Just tried it, the same thing happens. I made an issue on github.

Comment: The issue is closed, Luigi is right. Altough is a little bit misleading the fact that `limit` works (and in this case you expect that skip will work too). I've updated my answer with the `limit` in the right place. Sorry for the trouble.